# any number on Google App Engine free quota in terms of total number of request and unique visitors

Tags: google-app-engine

Does anyone have any number on Google App Engine (free quota)  in terms of total number of request and unique visitors it allows per day?
Maybe someone who has live production code can tell us this? 
Rough number is enough, just to get the idea. 
I can not get this information from the pricing model.
Thanks

Comment: that depens on your app. what do you expect people to answer here? what kind of app are you thinking to deploy? what framework are you using?

Comment: I know my question is not truly valid. I was looking for answer / experience like this: http://www.dev-articles.com/article/App-engine-new-pricing-model-456001

Comment: i understand but you are not giving the smallest information about what you want to do so answering will be pretty difficult.

Comment: yup, I should have given more details. How about site like reddit which is mostly text. How does caching play to help reduce bandwidth. Can we do optimization like etags, caching proxy server and all that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this question when I first started using App Engine, but it's impossible to answer with the information in your question.

You must have an estimate on the individual API quota usages, then calculate based on that.

You might be able to simplify it by trying to figure out which API quota you're likely to hit first, and then figuring out the number of requests you can serve before that quota runs out.  ie:

- Storing photos or other large data for users?  You'll probably hit the blobstore quota first.  Daily/unique visitor counts probably won't matter.
- Serving lots of photos or large data? You'll probably hit the bandwidth quota first.
- Need to start a channel for every view?  You'll probably hit the channel quota first and get 100 views per day.
- Need to send an email for every view?  You'll probably hit the mail quota first.
- Need to query the datastore a lot?  You'll probably hit the datastore limit first.

The datastore limit is the hardest to calculate.  You get 50k read and 50k write ops.  Most likely you'd read more than write.

- If you need 2 read ops per page, you might could do 25k views per day.
- If you need 2 read ops per page, but you're smart and you memcache them, and memcache is effective 80% of the time, you could get 125k views per day.
- If you need 500 read ops per page and you can't cache it, you can do 100 views per day.  That's provided you don't run out of one of the other quotas.

Do your own math.

Answer (score 0):

The quotas and rates (for free and paid apps) are listed on https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.